# How to merge two maps in parallel?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I have two large maps, as follows,

```
std::map<std::string, int> map1;
std::map<std::string, int> map2;
```

map2 may have some keys that not exist in map1.

Then I want to get the sum of values labeled by the same key, as follows,

```
// merging to map1
for(auto it=map2.begin(); it!=map2.end(); it++)
    map1[it->first] += it->second;
```

I want to parallelize the above code to improve its performance.

How could I do?

Comment: Notice that your algo is currently `O(n log m)` whereas it might be `O(n + m)` (with code similar to.. [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)).

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is iterating over a single map in parallel (read only).  If you have an idea of the distribution of the keys, you are good.

Editing the value in the map (not an insert) is safe to do in parallel.  **adding** elements is not.

The to-be-added elements can be seperate maps (one per worker thread) then merged into the destination map, but it fundamentally takes O(klg(n+k)) time to add k keys to a map of size n; if you record where each node will go you can get this down to O(k).  But this is a mutating operation on the entire container, so cannot be done in parallel.

(C++ lacks a way to guarantee that a range of sequential map nodes can be inserted in constant time).

However this cost only applies to keys in map 2 and not in map 1.  It this is a small number, and you can split the map 2 up by key into multiple equal-ish sized chunks, you are in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the maps contain unique entries and if one thread is only accessing strings from "aa-jz" and one thread is accessing strings from "ka-zz", then there will be no synchronisation issues -- given that you are not creating new entries to map1. Otherwise all the threads need to write to local maps.

Map2 needs to be split into (almost) similar sized chunks, which may be difficult to achieve.

Anyway, the **biggest optimization regardless of the parallelism should arrive from a search hint** -- as the map2 or blocks of map2 are processed in a sorted order, one can simply use the last iterator to map1 as the starting point where the corresponding key should be found.

**EDIT** the C++11/14/17/20 STL does have only an **insertion hint**, and not a search hint.

Another option then would be to serialise the maps into vectors and merge sort in complexity of O(N+K).

Answer (score 0):

Not answering about parallelism, but about performance:

Your algorithm is `O(n log m)`, whereas regular merge algorithm is `O(n + m)`:

```
auto it1 = map1.begin();
auto it2 = map2.begin();

while (it2 != map2.end()) { // no need of it1 != map1.end()
    if (it1->first < it2->first) {
        ++it1;
    } else { // it1->first == it2->first as map1 has all keys
        it2->second += it1->second;
        ++it1;
        ++it2;
    }
}
```

Note: Merge code simplified as `map1` contains all keys from `map2`.